# Exporting python.exe in unity android build version

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a 3D debugger in unity which takes python file as input and then displays live memory allocation of objects in python code.

---

The problem is that I want to run python3 in unity and only possible way I can see is to execute it through C#. But then I need to have python.exe file in the system.
I am thinking of converting python.exe to .dll file but I am not sure about how that will work and also not sure how can convert python.exe to .dll.

---

I have also read about python for unity but the problem is it only supports python2 and from their site I could only understand that python2 is not included in unity build version.
Please help me with this situation. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like it would be better to communicate with your Unity program over a local network socket from the Python application rather than trying to embed it.

Comment: @AKX  I already saw that but I don't really understand about how can that work. It would be really helpful, If you could explain the idea, or share some resources of how I can do that

Comment: How would your debugger/profiler work in the first place? Instead of directly talking to Python (however you're planning to do it), talk to it over a network connection.

Comment: The goal is to show how the memory being allocated to python objects. I would really like to know that how talking over a network connection can be helpful?

Comment: Well, for one, you're already seeing you have trouble running Python _in_ Unity :-) But in general, separation of concerns. If all your Unity tool needs is, say, a list of object types, counts and sizes to draw what it needs, it suddenly becomes usable with not just Python but anything that can talk that protocol.